# Set boolean variable in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

This might be a silly question, but I just can't get it to work. Pretty sure I've missed something.

I want to set a boolean to `false`
Then set it to `true` only when a condition is met.

```
boolTest = false

until boolTest = true
    puts "Enter one fo these choices: add / update / display / delete?"
    choice = gets.chomp.downcase

    if choice == "add" || choice == "update" || choice == "display" || choice == "delete"
        boolTest = true
    end
end
```

Only just starting to learn Ruby, so maybe I'm confusing the capabilities of other languages.

Comment: `boolTest = true`, don't add quotes.

Comment: Also, according to ruby conventions, should be `bool_test` (snake_case), not `boolTest` (camelCase).

Comment: apologies I copied the wrong code I didnt have quote in the original

Comment: here's another error. `until boolTest == true`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since you're using `until`, that's effectively writing out `while not boolTest`.  You can't use `=`, since that's reserved for assignment; instead, omit the boolean conditional.
  There's no value in checking a boolean against a boolean; if you really wanted to keep it though, you'd have to use `==`.

```
boolTest = false

until boolTest
  puts "Enter one fo these choices: add / update / display / delete?"
  choice = gets.chomp.downcase

  if choice == "add" || choice == "update" || choice == "display" || choice == "delete"
    boolTest = true
  end
end
```

As an optimization/readability tip, you can also adjust your boolean conditional so that there's no repeated statement with `choice`; you can declare all of thoe strings in an array, and check to see if `choice` exists in the array through `include?`.

```
boolTest = false

until boolTest
  puts "Enter one fo these choices: add / update / display / delete?"
  choice = gets.chomp.downcase

  boolTest = %w(add update display delete).include? choice
end
```

Comment: Your answer is now invalid :)

Comment: ah so I cannot write `until boolTest = True` - because now it seems to work

Comment: @cocojay `=` is an *assignment*, you have to use `==`

Answer (score 1):

I think what you missed is just `"=="` in the `if condition`  `until boolTest = true` you should use a double = not a single one

this will work for you

```
boolTest = false

until boolTest == true
  puts "Enter one fo these choices: add / update / display / delete?"
  choice = gets.chomp.downcase

  if choice == "add" || choice == "update" || choice == "display" || choice == "delete"
    boolTest = true
  end
end
```